# Laravel Scheduling - Is a Domain Name Required

Tags: php, laravel, hosting, vps

Is a domain name required to run chronjobs in a Laravel application on a server? Or can I get by without it? There will be no human interaction with this application, only day-to-day automated tasks.

My understanding is that for a regular Laravel application, you are required to configure the apache `.conf` file to link the server files & `var/www/<laravel_application>` with the world.

Is there a conventional way to achieve this without a domain name? Or should I set up a new domain name?

*Note: Not sure if this is important, but it's a VPS server*

*Update: I forgot to mention that this application will interact with APIs elsewhere on the web.*

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sure, it's possible. You only have to follow instructions on [Task Scheduling](https://laravel.com/docs/5.3/scheduling) docs page. Laravel scheduler/commands do not require any acces via web.

You just need to add this line (taken from docs) to crontab on your server

```
* * * * * php /path/to/artisan schedule:run >> /dev/null 2>&1
```

Comment: Makes sense. I forgot to mention that this is interacting with third party APIs that require access to the web.

Comment: As long as your app is connected to the internet it should not be problem. Of course if this third party API is accessible via web :)

Answer (score 0):

Let's see, the domain is for web access, if you don't need to provide nothing over HTTP ports, then I don't see why you would need to buy some domain, you can perfectly deploy the app in a server, and if it is a VPS, even better, because of the freedom of settings you have, my final answer is, no, you don't need any domain, you can achieve this by feeling the server where your app is deployed as your own PC, making the regards configurations, and start the services you need.